# wget -O yields error on Windows

Tags: wget

I am trying to download bootstrap using wget on Windows and I am getting an error. I got roughly the same error using Powershell and the Git Shell. My command is as follows:

```
wget -O bootstrap.zip https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.0/bootstrap-3.1.0-dist.zip
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name
'O' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -OutFile -OutVariable -OutBuffer.
At line:1 char:6
+ wget -O bootstrap.zip
...
```

I see that -O is documented as an option in online man pages. Which option should I use in place of -O (dash capital oh)?

Note: this command is exactly as provided in the book "Test-Driven Development with Python" by Harry J.W. Percival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following command:

```
wget -OutFile bootstrap.zip https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.0/bootstrap-3.1.0-dist.zip
```

This specifies that your wget output should be sent to the OutFile `bootstrap.zip`